# Why ignore settings in .gitignore file in submodule

Tags: android, git

In my project I use 3 .gitignore files:

in myproject/.gitignore

```
*.iml
.gradle
.idea
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
/app/src/test
/app/src/androidTest
/app/src/debug/
/app/src/release/
/app/build
```

in `app/.gitignore`:

/build

and in `library/.gitignore`:

```
/build
```

But when I start Git client it's show me files in folder `library/build/`

[image: mo]

why?

Comment: are you sure you didn't add those files to git before adding them to a git ignore ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'm did'n add this files to git before adding them to git ignore.